# What is Jackson stands for - in many jar in java world?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Jackson is an author name or an organization name? Or does it mean something else.

For example, I am using following jars. I would like to understand the reason for the name, ownership and relationship between these jars.

jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.8.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.8.jar
jackson-core-2.9.0.jar
jackson-databind-2.9.0.jar
jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar

Comment: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson

Comment: developed by the jackson five

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not "The History Channel".

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is a JSON processor for Java POJOs to convert from/to JSON.

These Jars will have annotations to do the work related JSON operations.